# "Does $\{\exists xPx, \neg Pa_{0}, \neg Pa_{1}, \neg Pa_{2},\dots\}$ have a model?"

Tags: first-order-logic

I was taking a casual look over the exercises at the end of some section in Endertons's logic book and stumbled upon this one. Again,

> Does the set of sentences $\Sigma=\{\exists xPx, \neg Pa_{0}, \neg Pa_{1}, \neg Pa_{2},\dots\}$ have a model?

[I am not sure if the exercise was exactly this, as I only caught a glimpse of it, but in any case, it got me wondering about what I am going to ask here]

Well, it trivially does: take any $\mathfrak{A}$ where the $x$ of the universe such that $x \in P^{\mathfrak{A}}$ is not denoted by any constant symbol nor <s>definable</s> representable by any formula in the language — the idea is that the system has to "construct" it somehow.

For instance, a structure $(\mathbb{N}; 1, <, \mathbf{S})$ with $Px$ being $\forall y(x<y)$.

Now, I always had a hard time grasping $\omega$-inconsistency, nonstandard models of arithmetics and the like: a system proving $Pk$ for every $k$ but not proving $\forall xPx$ sounded unintuitive—it is just that the "for every $k$" quantifies over all definable elements, while the one inside the formal sentence in turn quantifies over all elements.

Thus, is it merely the case that, for example, the model of $PA+\neg Con(PA)$ has its element $x$ of the universe such that $x$, say, is the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from the axioms of $PA$, not definable? Is this essentially what $\omega$-inconsistency is all about?

For instance, take the language containing parameter $\mathbf{S}$, $<$ and some constant symbol. Then, is the set of sentences of this language

1. $\forall x,y(x=y\leftrightarrow\mathbf{S}x=\mathbf{S}y)$, (successor is unique);
2. $\forall x,y(\mathbf{S}x=y \to (x<y\wedge\forall z\neg(x<z\wedge z<y)))$, (successor is immediately "to the right");
3. $\forall x,y,z(x<y \wedge y<z \to x<z)$, (ordering is transitive);
4. $\forall x,y(x<y\oplus y<x \oplus x=y)$, (trichotomy);
5. $\exists x \forall y (x<y)$.

(plus any others I might have forgot, you get the idea of what I'm trying to do I guess)

$\omega$-inconsistent?

Answer (score 1):

No. Remember that $PA$ includes *induction*, so if $M\models PA$ then any *definable* nonempty subset $D$ of $M$ has a least element. This least element is, in turn, definable: it is the unique element $x$ satisfying $$\varphi(x)\wedge\forall y(y<x\implies \neg\varphi(y)),$$ where $\varphi$ is the formula defining $D$.

So what? Well, in any $M\models PA$, the set of (codes of) $PA$-proofs of $0=1$ is a definable set! Moreover, if $M$ thinks $PA$ is inconsistent, this set is nonempty; so in such an $M$ there is a *definable* element of $M$ coding (what $M$ thinks is) a $PA$-proof of $0=1$.

So it is wrong to conflate the *definable* elements of a nonstandard model $M\models PA$ with the *standard* elements: although every standard element is definable, the converse may fail.

In fact, we can generalize the above fact (with some work) to prove the following:

> Let $M\models PA$. Then either $M$ has a definable nonstandard element, or $M$ is in fact a model of *true arithmetic* $TA$.

Proof sketch: suppose $M\not\models TA$. We'll find a definable element of $M$ which is nonstandard; specifically, we'll look at the "simplest" difference between the theory of $M$ and true arithmetic, and show that the least witness to this difference must be a definable nonstandard element of $M$.

Let $n$ be the least (standard) natural number such that, for some $\varphi\in TA\cap(\Sigma_n\cup\Pi_n)$,  $M\not\models\varphi$ (so $n$ is the first level of the [arithmetic hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) where we see that $M$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have different theories); and pick such a $\varphi$.

First, I claim that $\varphi$ can't be $\Sigma_n$. Why? Well, suppose it were. Write $\varphi$ as $\exists x\psi(x)$ for some $\Pi_{n-1}$ formula $\psi$. (I'm implicitly assuming $n>0$ here, but it's easy to show that $PA$ is in fact $\Sigma_0$-complete, so in fact we'll always have $n>0$.) Since $\varphi\in TA$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N}\models\psi(n)$. But $n$ is definable, being standard; so we can write this as $\mathbb{N}\models \chi$ for a parameter-free sentence $\chi$ (namely, $\chi\equiv\psi(\underline{n})$, where $\underline{n}$ is the numeral for $n$). Well, $\chi$ is $\Pi_{n-1}$, so by assumption on $n$ we have $M\models\chi$. But then $M\models\exists x\psi(x)$, since $x=n$ satisfies $\psi$ in $M$.

So $\varphi$ must be $\Pi_n$. Write $\varphi$ as $\forall x\theta(x)$ for some $\Sigma_{n-1}$ formula $\theta$, and let $$D=\{m\in M: M\models \theta(m)\}.$$ This set is nonempty (since we're assuming $M\not\models\varphi$) and definable, so it has a least element $d\in M$. This $d$ is definable. But $d$ must be nonstandard, since the statement "$\neg\theta(m)$" for every standard natural $m$ is $\Pi_{n-1}$ and true in $\mathbb{N}$, so (by assumption on $n$) true in $M$. So we are done.

---

Re: the example you give, first a couple comments:

- I don't recommend using "$\oplus$" for "xor"; since we use "$\oplus$" frequently to denote a binary function symbol or direct sum of structures, it would become dangerously overloaded.
- I think you also want axioms asserting "$c>SSSS...S(0)$" for every finite string of $S$s (where $c$ is your new constant symbol).

That said - assuming my second bullet is correct - **yes**, this is an example of a consistent, $\omega$-inconsistent theory: it proves "$c>\underline{k}$" for every natural number $k$ (where $\underline{k}$ is the numeral for $k$: $SSSSS...S(0)$, with $k$-many $S$s), but *disproves* "$\forall x(c>x)$".

Comment: Oh. Didn't know first-order $PA$ had induction. I need to read up before playing further with those things. While I digest your post, can you comment on the other parts of the OP not concerning $PA$? That is, my proposed model for the set in the title and about the $\omega$-inconsistency of that set of sentences in the end?

Comment: @wet $PA$ doesn't have *second-order* induction, but it does have the *induction scheme*: for every formula $\varphi(x, \overline{y})$ in the language of arithmetic, $PA$ contains the axiom $$\mbox{"$\forall \overline{z}[\varphi(0,\overline{z})\wedge\forall y(\varphi(y, \overline{z})\implies \varphi(y+1, \overline{z})\implies \forall y(\varphi(y, \overline{z}))]$."}$$ What this means in words (and switching from *induction* to *infinite descent*) is that any definable subset of a model of $PA$ has a least element.

Comment: @wet See my edit. Incidentally, the way you should think about the standard cut of a model of $PA$ is not as the *definable* elements, but rather as the *elements named by terms*; this is really the crucial distinction. Every standard natural number has a term picking it out, while no nonstandard one does. That is, $\mathbb{N}$ is the *term model* of $PA$ (note that despite the name, the term model of a theory might not actually satisfy the theory - or even be nonempty! any theory in a relational language has no terms at all).

Comment: Yes. My intuition was that the elements had to be "constructible" by the system. I figured "denoted by some constant term" was much too restrictive so I, without thinking too much, dumped "definable" in there as well. After reading your post, I now see it — definability is "nonconstructive" and much too generous a property. Perhaps I should exchange it for representable — I will edit my post now. In any case, I am interested in the intuitive side of it all: the system is $\omega$-inconsistent if the $x$ s.t. $Px$ is not "constructible" — however we choose to formalise that — in the system...

Comment: ...so, if we formalize it as "denoted by closed term or representable" (or only "denoted by closed term"), does my reasoning hold? Is, in essence, what's going in behind the $\omega$-inconsistency of $PA+\neg Con(PA)$ the same as with the set of sentences I proposed in the end — the element that "realises" the existential sentence is not "constructible"?

Comment: (Just saw your latest edit. Hold on a moment, I'll read it. $\oplus$ was meant to denote XOR, not OR, BTW)

Comment: @wet Yes, the modified intuition you've described is essentially right.